# Publishing a game on Steam without going throught Greenlight

Tags: publishing, steam

Is there any possible way to publish a game on Steam without going through Steam Greenlight?

Answer (score 4):

If you are already on Steam as a publisher, then you can post other games after a short evaluation by them.

In the past (before Greenlight) you could enter by personally asking them. A contract was custom made for you and off you went.

Once Greenlight started, that option ceased to exist and the only way to accept new publishers is that option.

Comment: In my opinion, having a game get evaluated by steam workers was better, than the system nowadays. It could maybe make games like the airport simulator or the rock simulator was not existent.